curl: error while loading shared libraries: liblber-2.5.so.0
I upgraded from Ubuntu 24.04 to 24.04.1 LTS and after the upgrade my curl no longer works
curl ifconfig.me
curl: error while loading shared libraries: liblber-2.5.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have tried reinstalling via both apt remove and apt install --reinstall
apt install liblber-2.5 doesn't find a suitable match
I have tried to install via snap (after removing via apt), but that did not work either.
Curl was functioning properly before the upgrade.
Additional Info:
which curl
/usr/bin/curl

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

ldd $(which curl)
/usr/bin/curl: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/curl)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd93fda000)
        libcurl.so.4 => /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4 (0x000075f584692000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x000075f584676000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x000075f584400000)
        liblber-2.5.so.0 => not found
        libldap-2.5.so.0 => not found
        libcares.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libcares.so.2 (0x000075f584644000)
        libssl.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 (0x000075f584356000)
        libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x000075f583e00000)
        libnghttp2.so.14 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x000075f584619000)
        libbrotlidec.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x000075f584348000)
        libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x000075f583d46000)
        libpsl.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5 (0x000075f584334000)
        libssh2.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh2.so.1 (0x000075f583cfe000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000075f58479f000)
        libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x000075f583cdb000)
        libunistring.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.5 (0x000075f583b2e000)
        libidn2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x000075f583b0c000)


What exactly did you you remove and reinstall? The package that contains liblber-2.5.so.0 is libldap-2.5-0'. It also provides libldap-2.5.so.0which is also missing. Also, I updated from Ubuntu 24.04 to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS as well and the library thatcurlneeds isliblber.so.2whereas yours specifiedliblber-2.5.so.0. From what I can see, the latter is available in Debian but the latest in Ubuntu is  liblber.so.2`. Is the package containing the library actually installed on your system?

@NasirRiley I reinstalled the entire curl package

Is libldap-2.5-0 actually installed on your system? That is the package that contains liblber-2.5.so.0 which is what curl is reporting to not be able to find. From what I have using the same release of Ubuntu, the output gives liblber.so.2 which is provided by libldap2. Are either of those packages installed on your system?

Ensure that the library paths are correctly set. Sometimes, curl might not be able to find the libraries if they are installed in non-standard locations. You can check the library paths using:
ldd $(which curl)

This will list the shared libraries required by curl and their paths. Verify that all required libraries are present and correctly linked.
If the above steps do not resolve the issue, try reinstalling curl:
sudo apt-get remove --purge curl
sudo apt-get install curl


I have already done the above but I am still missing libraries, edited post with ldd output
